# Log out Pod Trunk Session

Tags: cocoapods

Like the title reads, say I authenticate myself by running this:

`pod trunk register myemail@email.com 'FirstName LastName' --description='my computer'`

How could I log myself out? Also, is there any way I could log out a specific session that came up from running `pod trunk me`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can log out with `pod trunk me clean-sessions`

```
  $ pod trunk me clean-sessions

  By default this will clean-up your sessions by removing expired and unverified
  sessions.

  To remove all your sessions, except for the one you are currently using, specify
  the `--all` flag.
```